# How to have icons on opposite sides in the same line?

Tags: html, css, class, alignment

I have tried all the answers I can find and can't seem to fix this. I'm trying to have one of the buttons on the left and the other on the right within the same line. I have tried using

```
<div style="text-align: right;clear:left;">
```

in either a div or a span tag and taking it out of the unordered list but I still can't seem to get it frustratingly! I think that I could do it by putting them in tables and floating one left and one right but that just seems a messy way to do it and I'm sure there's an easier way I just can't seem to find it. I'd be happy to allocate each a new class and then assign some new CSS to them but I can't seem to make it work that way either.

I have put my JSFiddle here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8L4Lqwo/) to illustrate the issue.

```
<span align="right">
  <ul class="actions">
    <li><a href="salary.html" class="button special icon fa-arrow-left">Salary</a></li>
    <li><a href="courses.html" class="button special icon fa-arrow-right">Courses</a></li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Thank you so much for your help,

S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the unnecessary span and simply use:

```
ul.actions li:last-of-type {
  float: right;
}
```

This leaves the first button totally unaltered, sitting on the left, and floats the second button to far right.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When doing this I get them on different lines; https://jsfiddle.net/48ff1zk6/ 

Of note I already have the following code in my CSS for the ul.actions li:

  ul.actions li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 6em 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }

Comment: HI, Then just float the first one left. There is nothing wrong with floating one left and one right, in fact it's quite semantic :)

Comment: Just got home now. Yes tried it straight away and it's worked. I've used an ID Selector and called one <i id="leftbutton"> and the other "rightbutton" and then in the CSS given them their corresponding float attributes. Same line and works when resizing the site as it's responsive. Brilliant. Thanks for that.